# spring-integration-ip get the client's ip when (dis)connected

Tags: java, sockets, spring-integration

My server is using spring-integration-ip,and the server-client connection is using long connection.My question is:if I can get the client's ip when connected or disconneted, such as the channelConnected() or channelDisconnected() method in Netty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not available with the current 2.2.x release.

The upcoming 3.0 release emits connect/disconnect events; see [what's new](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/3.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/whats-new.html#3.0-tcp-events). The event source is the connection and the `getHostAddress()` method on the connection returns the remote ip address.